# Cluster Autoscaling on AWS not scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

Stumped on this issue and hoping someone who knows more can help me.

Trying to follow a guide with a proof of concept for cluster autoscaling on AWS for Kubernetes (https://renzedevries.wordpress.com/2017/01/10/autoscaling-your-kubernetes-cluster-on-aws/). I built my cluster on AWS using kops following this guide (https://medium.com/containermind/how-to-create-a-kubernetes-cluster-on-aws-in-few-minutes-89dda10354f4).

The issue appears to be with the cluster autoscaling deployment. When I run:

`kubectl logs cluster-autoscaler-`

I get the following output:

```
I0706 13:26:36.338072       1 leaderelection.go:210] failed to renew 
lease kube-system/cluster-autoscaler
I0706 13:26:38.776977       1 leaderelection.go:210] failed to renew 
lease kube-system/cluster-autoscaler
I0706 13:26:43.119763       1 leaderelection.go:210] failed to renew 
lease kube-system/cluster-autoscaler
I0706 13:26:47.116439       1 leaderelection.go:210] failed to renew
```

I've been looking into the error and it was to do with the namespace. When I  run the pod in a different namespace or the namespace recommended (kube-system - https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/issues/2402) I still get the same error. Not sure what it causing it.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: [The code says](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/v8.0.0/tools/leaderelection/leaderelection.go#L18) it stores the current election state on the `Endpoints` object, so `kubectl get --all-namespaces=true --output=wide endpoints | grep -i autoscale` may help you find it, and then `kubectl --namespace=$the_ns get --output=yaml endpoints $endpoint_name` could surface who currently has the lease. It certainly smells like you have more than one cluster-autoscaler instance running, and you're looking at the logs for the "second" one

Answer (score 1):

Follow this guide here to configure Cluster Autoscaler for Kubernetes running in AWS.

[Configure Cluster Autoscaler in Kubernetes](https://samratpriyadarshi.com/2018/11/27/setup-cluster-autoscaler/)

It should do the work without any errors.

Comment: After trying five other methods for 8 hours were not working but this one working. Great work!!!

Comment: @samrat-priyadarshi
the link does not work. 
also, your blog link in the profile redirects to a scam website claiming to infect the computer with a virus